# C++ - creating an alias for an std::array of std::array iterator

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, alias

I have an array of iterators of type `std::array<Point, SIZE>::iterator`, where `SIZE` is a template variable.

So having an array of these iterators would be

```
std::array<std::array<Point, SIZE>::iterator, SIZE>
```

which is a pain to write in the number of functions that I have.

I was thinking of aliasing this type, but I don't know how, while having template variable `SIZE`.

I tried

```
template<std::size_t SIZE>
using p_iterators = std::array<std::array<Point, SIZE>::iterator, SIZE>;
```

And inside the function I did :

```
template<std::size_t SIZE>
template <typename T>
p_iterators<SIZE> eucledian_closest(T &points) {}
```

I got these errors:

```
closest_pair.cpp:24:70: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> struct std::array’
 using p_iterator = std::array<std::array<Point, SIZE>::iterator, SIZE>;
                                                                      ^
closest_pair.cpp:24:70: error:   expected a type, got ‘std::array<Point, SIZE>::iterator’
closest_pair.cpp:42:1: error: ‘p_iterator’ does not name a type
 p_iterator<SIZE> eucledian_closest(T &points) {
```

I don't know how to alias such a type or even how to use it with that template while having another template in the function `template <typename T>`.

Comment: `template<size_t SIZE, typename T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, [dependent](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_typename_disambiguator_for_dependent_names) template type names require the keyword, `typename`.

You should change your alias from

```
template<std::size_t SIZE>
using p_iterators = std::array<std::array<Point, SIZE>::iterator, SIZE>;
```

to

```
template<std::size_t SIZE>
using p_iterators = std::array<typename std::array<Point, SIZE>::iterator, SIZE>;
```

---

Then change the template function signature to this:

```
template<std::size_t SIZE, typename T>
p_iterators<SIZE> eucledian_closest(T &points) {}
```

In the above case, when calling the function, `eucledian_closest`, you will at least need to explicitly provide the `SIZE` parameter like `eucledian_closest<3>(myArry)`. Without doing so, type deduction will fail to deduce `SIZE`, plus the down side is that you should have the size to match. If you want type deduction to deduce it implicitly `SIZE` for you:

You can do something like:

```
template<template <typename, std::size_t> class Array,
                                          typename T,
                                          std::size_t SIZE
        >
p_iterators<SIZE> eucledian_closest(Array<T, SIZE>& points) {}
```

With the above, you can do `eucledian_closest(myArray)`. However, if you do not need to use `SIZE` in the function, you could simply do

```
template<typename T>
auto eucledian_closest(T& points) {}
```

And simply call it like `eucledian_closest(myArray)`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `typename` for your dependant type

```
template<std::size_t SIZE>
std::array<typename std::array<Point, SIZE>::iterator, SIZE>
```

By the way, the following function template doesn't make any sense:

```
template<std::size_t SIZE>
template <typename T>
p_iterators<SIZE> eucledian_closest(T &points) {}
```

You may only have one template parameter list for a free function template, you probably want

```
template<std::size_t SIZE, typename T>
p_iterators<SIZE> eucledian_closest(T &points) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers explain how to correct your alias. As to the function, I think there are several ways to fix this. The easiest one is to use type deduction for the returned value, which you can apply if you expect T to be of the std::array type:

```
template <typename T>
auto euclidean_closest(T& points) { 
  // some code
  T some_arr;  // the compiler will know what size to use
  return some_arr;
}
```

If you need to provide the SIZE, you can use:

```
template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
p_iterators<SIZE> euclidean_closest(T& points) {}
```